# Stretch underbrace VERTICALLY or make the pointing part of underbrace bigger in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, equation-editor

I use Microsoft Word to edit an equation with underbrace. The line is as follows:

`\underbrace(ab+cdf-edf=9dc/ereat+asdfdgg-asfeefe-eafdgahty+atataeaattrat)`

The problem is the symbol for underbrace is very flat, looking like a line with the downward pointing part too small to see, as shown:

[image: the equation]

Is there a way to make it larger (e.g., is there a way to stretch the underbrace ***vertically***)?

The size of underbrace is set automatically in LaTeX and looks fine, but in Microsoft Word the default just does not look right, especially when you have a long equation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is.  I checked [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.omath_members(v=office.14).aspx) and [UTN28](http://unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf) (which defines the inner syntax of `OMath` objects) and didn't see anything.  If you've found anything since you asked this question, would you please post?